# AWK split output with the line

Tags: awk

How can I split output lines using tailf and awk like this?

From this:

```
tail -f logfile.log | awk '/connected/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m"}'
```

Output:

```
2018-01-31 10:00 user connected autentication successful
2018-01-31 10:10 user connected autentication successful
2018-01-31 10:23 user connected autentication successful
2018-01-31 10:34 user connected autentication unsuccessful
2018-01-31 10:35 user connected autentication unsuccessful
```

To this output:

```
2018-01-31 10:00 user connected autentication successful
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-31 10:10 user connected autentication successful
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-31 10:23 user connected autentication successful
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-31 10:34 user connected autentication unsuccessful
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-31 10:35 user connected autentication unsuccessful
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the separator lines to be white:

```
tail -f logfile.log | awk '/connected/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\033[39m\n-----------------------------------"}'
```

If you want the separator line to be red:

```
tail -f logfile.log | awk '/connected/ {print "\033[31m" $0 "\n-----------------------------------\033[39m"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is print `----------------------------------------------------------` after every line, set the ORS (output record separator) to whatever you want to come after every line:

```
$ awk -v ORS='\033[39m\n----------------------------------------------------------\n' '/connected/ {print "\033[31m" $0}' foo
2018-01-31 10:00 user connected autentication successful
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-31 10:10 user connected autentication successful
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-31 10:23 user connected autentication successful
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-31 10:34 user connected autentication unsuccessful
----------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-31 10:35 user connected autentication unsuccessful
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Here, I moved the `\033[39m` to the ORS from the `print` command, and surrounded the hyphens with newlines (`\n`).